# ClsModule isn't initialized correctly

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to use the [ClsModule](https://github.com/Papooch/nestjs-cls/blob/main/README.md) in a NestJS app, in order to use some header values during the lifetime of HTTP requests, but it doesn't seem to initialize correctly.

My app module is like this:

```
@Module({ 
    imports: [
        ClsModule.forRoot({
            middleware: { 
            mount: true,
            setup: (cls, req: Request, res: Response) => {
                cls.set('userId', req.headers[HttpHeaders.UserId])
            },
        },
        }),
        ConfigModule.forRoot(),
        EventModule,
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_GUARD,
            useFactory: async (moduleRef: ModuleRef) => {
                const reflector = moduleRef.get(Reflector)
                const configService = moduleRef.get(ConfigService)
                return new AuthGuard(reflector, configService)
            },
            inject: [ModuleRef],
        },
        Reflector,
        ConfigService,
    ],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): void {
        consumer.apply(RequestMiddleware).forRoutes('*')
    }
}
```

but, for some reason, this line in the ClsModule finds an undefined this.moduleRef, because the constructor is never called:

`options = this.moduleRef.get(cls_constants_1.CLS_MIDDLEWARE_OPTIONS);`

In a sample nestjs I have created, the constructor is called fine and the ClsModule works as expected. I also see this log during app initialization:

> DEBUG [ClsModule] Mounting ClsMiddleware to *

I've tried removing all other modules, middlewares etc. from my app, in order to come closer to the sample app, but still, when I try to use the ClsService I can't, and this is what I get when logging it:

```
cls: ClsService {
    als: AsyncLocalStorage {
        kResourceStore: Symbol(kResourceStore),
        enabled: false,
        _onPropagate: null
    }
}
```